# React Native Expo Firebase Firestore (9.9.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My config file:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, setDoc, doc, getDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx"
};


if (!firebase.getApps().length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
const firestore = getFirestore(firebase.getApp());


export { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential, firestore, setDoc, doc, getDoc, updateDoc };
export default firebase;
```

When I try to `setDoc` or `getDoc` it always throws the following error:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

or
`[FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.]`

I've also tried with versions 9.9.2, 9.9.1, 9.9.0 and 9.8.0 but always the same... Any idea why I cannot connect? My internet connection is stable and I've tried it on my Android phone and emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The following setting for firestore solved the problem:

```js
import { getFirestore, initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

if (!firebase.getApps().length) {
    const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    initializeFirestore(app, { experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true });
}
```